# Get default output audio device

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

With Delphi 11 and FMX, I can easily retrieve the default audio capture device using the following code:

```
var
  LAudioCapture : TAudioCaptureDevice;
  LUniqueID: string;
begin
  // getting the default mic
  LAudioCapture := TCaptureDeviceManager.Current.DefaultAudioCaptureDevice;
  if Assigned(LAudioCapture) then
  begin
    LUniqueID := LAudioCapture.UniqueID;
  end;
end;
```

There is a similar process to retrieve the default video device using `DefaultVideoCaptureDevice`.

However, I couldn't find a way to retrieve the default output audio device using anything in the `FMX.Media` unit (for Windows & Mac). I currently have a lot of code to do it and I'm hoping to simplify it.

Did I miss anything?

Comment: I do not know the solution but i just want to say that you are on the good way when you are using L in front of your local variable :)

Comment: As far as I know, there is nothing "out of the box" to do what you request. The process will be different for each platform, so the answer would probably be fairly extensive if you wanted to handle all platforms.

Comment: only mac and win :)